# LinkedList temp.next and temp?

Tags: java, linked-list

So I was practicing some linked list problems and I keep getting mixed up with let say we do 
// this is a head only singly linked list

```
// what is the difference between 

ListNode temp = head;
while( temp != null ) {
    temp = temp.next ; 
} 

while( temp.next != null ) {
    temp = temp.next ; 
}
```

again what is the difference between the two ? If you can please explain to me this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example terminates when `temp == null`, meaning that `temp` will have the value null after the loop and not be of much use to you, though for processing the items in the list this is a perfectly valid approach.

The second example will stop when `temp.next == null` but temp itself actually has a value, in this case it will be a reference to the tail of the list, which is far more useful if you want to add something else on to the list as well.

As some others have indicated, the second will cause a null dereference exception if temp is null, but this would only be an issue if temp was null before processing the loop, so this can be averted with a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

the first will stop one link later than the second one so if you want to process every node then use the first.

Comment: so if I am trying to do removeLast I should do while (temp.next != null) { temp = temp.next} temp.next = null; // am I thinking about it right ?

Comment: To remove the last one you would need to do while(temp.next != null) {temp = temp.next} temp = null;  The loop will exit when you are on the last node (the first one which has it's next as null) so temp will hold the last node at the end of the loop.  To clarify what I said before, the first way will let you touch every node and do processing inside the loop but exit with null in temp, the second way will touch every node except the last node inside the loop but exit with the last node in temp.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The second has a potential of getting NullPointerException if temp itself is null when checking the while condition for the first time. The first is safe from such exception.

The second would end up in the last element in the linked list, while the first would end up in null.

Answer (score 0):

The second loop will generate a nullPointerException while executing the condition so it is not an efficient way.